# typescript bug '[...Array, 1]["length"]' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATCmA8AcHsCcBdjwJ6VMAogOwMbQCagA8AUCCAMpjjyhb4DOwD8sAllgOYA0Z5ASvCzVa9Ji3ZdgAXmAByOb3LAAMgEMWIuo2asOnGfMV8QAQViw1yLWOABGANoBdQ86Xk2DAGJtYmiKI6AEbQ0AA2oGrCsqwArqB8AHyGVAHaTAAGACQA3hwAZqCwwF4AvrkFRcD8pRkmwAD8wJ4+fohptnEJyiBN2HiERPzc1UIjXiMOAHQz5pbII3ZOI-lqYQygifUgAFwlNjrqLNuNmLgExMOjWOOTM1NzVovLwKvrmyd7-RekPT3DJ2Uj2QDjkES48AAFnIXB0dHZAT0mtkcoIsOUckd4LVEco9ii0RjgaDwZwoTCMVjau4-iAJrjgA4ljTaW8NoitnjgKkaOlVBp4PVkblCblprMLE97E4SXQydCnJSBTiuQShEqWLUgA

It should not have an error here. Is it a ts bug ?

```
  export type Encode<
    S extends string,
    Rtn extends string = '',
    Last extends string = '',
    Array extends 1[] = [],
    isFirst extends boolean = true
  > = S extends `${infer F}${infer R}`
    ? isFirst extends true
      ? Encode<R, Rtn, F, [...Array, 1], false>
      : F extends Last
      ? Encode<R, Rtn, F, [...Array, 1], false>
      : Encode<
          R,
          Array['length'] extends 1
            ? `${Rtn}${Last}`
            : `${Rtn}${Array['length']}${Last}`,
          F,
          [1],
          false
        >
    : S extends Last
    ? `${Rtn}${[...Array, 1]['length']}${Last}` 
      // error , Type '[...Array, 1]["length"]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'
      // but [...Array, 1]['length'] is number
    : `${Rtn}${Last}`
```

```
type a1 = Encode<'AAABCCXXXXXXYYY'> // '3AB2C6X3Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given type definition:

> type a1 = Encode<'AAABCCXXXXXXYYY'>

If the expected type is `'3AB2C6X3Y'`, then the correct type definition of `Encode` should be:

```
type Encode<
    S extends string,
    Rtn extends string = '',
    Last extends string = '',
    Array extends 1[] = [],
    isFirst extends boolean = true
  > = S extends `${infer F}${infer R}`
    ? isFirst extends true
      ? Encode<R, Rtn, F, [...Array, 1], false>
      : F extends Last
      ? Encode<R, Rtn, F, [...Array, 1], false>
      : Encode<
          R,
          Array['length'] extends 1
            ? `${Rtn}${Last}`
            : `${Rtn}${Array['length']}${Last}`,
          F,
          [1],
          false
        >
    : S extends Last
    ? `${Rtn}${Last}`
    : `${Rtn}${Array['length']}${Last}`
```

The compilation error is because typescript is not able to infer the type of `[...Array, 1]['length']`. You can use another conditional typing (`[...Array, 1]['length'] extends 1 ? <> : <>`) to tell typescript to treat the value of `[...Array, 1]['length']` as a type in the template string. See [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATAuE8AcFNgUQHYGMD2ATaAeAUCEBlYaAD1GgTQGdhLQAnASwQHMAaXPAJVASNPKo16TZsAC8wAOST2eYABkAhrT5kK1WoxbipMjiACCdOovCqB1AIwBtALo67svA0oAxBnRUk1ggEYoUABtoRV4JegBXaA4APh1CbwtgAAMAEgBvJgAzaDpgVwBfDOzc4E4C5P1gAH5gF3dPUHN1MDooqpBaxFQMTE5WMp4B1wHrADoJoxNwActbAazFQMpoGI7gAC585sElWnWu5HQsfsGEYdGJsanTWfngReXV9a3u45w5T7KnL8NjU2skmCLFAAAtJPZEi1LOsvrU0uluAgiuk9qAKrDPlsEUiUTdwIDgcwwRCUWiKj9fiNMSBrHNKV9HitMWs5FsEvwWmiqrVxpN-jNgHNCeRieDIZzBJYaikMriMnzrgK7iKQeKycp0clNrLETwNbQMWzdfL0vjVWLSRlyckgA).

Comment: thanks for sharing , I used [...Array, 1]['length'] extends number ? <> : <> to solve this